# How to send particular row id to a new table in database using ajax codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have datatable that contains information like id, casename , productname and assign button.

when i click on assign button bootstrap modal will pop-up for that particular  row id.

In bootstrap modal i have dropdown option like lead1 and lead2.

when i click on lead1 or lead2 that particular row id should be sent to the new table in the same database.

view for boostrap modal:

```
<!--Send Module start here-->
<div id="assignModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Assign</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form action="#" id="Sendform" class="form-horizontal">
                <h4>Please select to whom you want to send this case?</h4> 
                   <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Assign To</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <select name="Assign To" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">--Select Leader--</option>
                               <?php foreach($lists as $list) { ?>  
  <option value="<?php echo $list['id'];?>">Lead1</option> 
  <option value="<?php echo $list['id'];?>">Lead2</option> 

  <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                </form>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSend" onclick="send()" class="btn btn-danger">Send</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

send function in view

```
function send()
{
    $('#btnSend').text('saving...'); //change button text
    $('#btnSend').attr('disabled',true); //set button disable 



    // ajax adding data to database
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('tracking/ajax_send')?>"+id,
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#Sendform').serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {

            if(data.status) //if success close modal and reload ajax table
            {
                $('#assignModal').modal('hide');
                reloadTable();
            }
            else
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++) 
                {
                    $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('has-error'); //select parent twice to select div form-group class and add has-error class
                    $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); //select span help-block class set text error string
                }
            }
            $('#btnSend').text('send'); //change button text
            $('#btnSend').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 


        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error update data');
            $('#btnSend').text('send'); //change button text
            $('#btnSend').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 

        }
    });
}
```

note:- i dont know how to get value for id using foreach loop.

when i choose  lead1 or lead2 in boostrap modal and click send button, that particular row id should be present in new table called case_assignment in same database.

case_assignment  table contains column like id,lead_name,case_assigned_date.

im new to programing and please help  me to proceed.

Comment: 1. please provide a `print_r($list)`, 2. explain `$row[]` where is this, what does it do?, 3. what is `send()`, put the function here.

Comment: @Alex Firstly  Here is the print_r($list)  stdClass Object
(
    [case_id] => A0000016
    [case_name] => Philips
    [firm_name] => Bifulco
    [id] => 16
    [deleteflag] => 
    [case_description] => Leg Injury
    [service_names] => Chronology,
LCP,
Hyperlink & Bookmark
    [specific_instruction] => Please capture all the treatment related to injury
    [priority] => High
    [received_date] => 2019-05-02 00:00:00
    [expected_delivery_date] => 2019-05-10 00:00:00
    [actual_delivery_date] => 
    [service_status] => 
)

Comment: 2. $row[]   i have added all the ajax_list im getting from database. 
3.send () function is to send the particular selected id   from the main (ajax_list) datatable  to a new table called case_assignment in same database.  case_assignment table contains column like id,lead_name,case_assigned_date.

Comment: you have changed your code a bit since the last time I commented. the `list` i was referring to was the one regarding your foreach loop: `view for boostrap modal`, so what is that var_dump?. please add your `send()` function should be present above as it is directly related to your primary problem. also what is the foreign key relationships/relationships between the `case_assignment` table and the one used in `ajax_list`?

Comment: typicially if `case_assignment` references something in the other table there would be two ids, the lead assigned (foreign key to the lead list table), and the id from the table the lead is connected to (foreign key to the cases table e.g. the one in ajax list). please clarify those points.

Comment: There is no foreign key, all the tables have id and i use left join.. Im not getting any output for var_dump and using send function im getting error like tracking:359 Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined

Comment: you really should implement foreign keys, and revise you data structure as previously mentioned. with that being said, if you aren't getting any output from the var_dump you must have an error somewhere when sending the `$list` data to the view. that code isn't here, so i can't know what that is. you kindof need to do some debugging on your own.

Comment: Thanks for helping.. i solved the error and its working!!!